# How to use omnet and inet4 UdpSocket to build an socket app?

Tags: c++, sockets, omnet++, inet

I want to use UdpSocket to build an App . All files are in the current directory.

Step 1: new omnet project(include files: WirelessNetwork.ned, omnetpp.ini) ;

Step 2: new simple Module: MyApp(MyApp.ned,MyApp.cc,MyApp.h);  (run no error)

Step 3: edit MyApp,code as follow:

```
***/*MyApp.ned*/
import inet.applications.contract.IApp;
simple MyApp like IApp
{
   parameters:
       int destAddr;
       int srcAddr;
       int destPort;
       int srcPort;
   gates:
       input socketIn ;
       output socketOut; 
}
/*MyApp.h*/
#ifndef __TWOWILESS_MYAPP_H_
#define __TWOWILESS_MYAPP_H_
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"
#include "inet/applications/base/ApplicationBase.h"
#include "inet/transportlayer/contract/udp/UdpSocket.h"
#include "inet/common/packet/Packet.h"
/**
 * TODO - Generated class
 */
namespace inet{
class MyApp : public cSimpleModule, public UdpSocket::ICallback
{
  protected:
    virtual void initialize();
    virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);
    void socketDataArrived(UdpSocket *socket, Packet *packet);
};
}
#endif
/*MyApp.cc*/
#include "inet/common/packet/Packet.h"
#include "MyApp.h"
namespace inet{
Define_Module(MyApp);
void MyApp::initialize()
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
}
void MyApp::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
}
void MyApp::socketDataArrived(UdpSocket *socket, Packet *packet)
{
}
}***
```

Step 4: build project, error.

Comment: What error do you get during build?

Comment: MyApp.cc:19:15: error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'inet::MyApp'
Define_Module(MyApp);。 When I delete "namespace inet {}“ in the  MyApp.h and MyApp.c, errors as follow:error: unknown class name 'cSimpleModule'; did you mean 'inet::cSimpleModule'? error: use of undeclared identifier 'UdpSocket'; did you mean 'inet::UdpSocket'? etc.  Thanks!